# Plot graphs over each other

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I was wondering if it's possible to compare graphs by plotting them over each other? I want to compare three graphs and I want to manipulate the zero-point of the y-axis (I need three different zero-points) so that they are plotted over each other.

Is this even possible in Excel?

[I want to make this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuYrM.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this:

1. Sparklines can make miniature, in-cell line charts that can be directly compared.  They're great for quick visualizations, but don't have much detail.

[image: sparklines]

2. You can make a series of small charts that you stack visually on the sheet.  Start with getting one designed/formatted the way you like, then copy and change the data series on each subsequent copy.  To align, turn on Snap to Grid in the Page Layout section of the ribbon.

[image: stackedcharts]

3. You can plot all your data in one chart and by manipulating your Y-series data (e.g. add 100 to each consecutive series to separate the series vertically) you can "cheat" the appearance of the chart, making it appear that each series is on it's own horizontal axis.

[image: modified_vertical_axis]

Once you choose a method, the rest is just selecting data and formatting.